# Post several forms with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

i have a very difficult one today for you to help me

this is my xhtml

```
<iframe id="myFrame0" name="myFrame" ></iframe>
<iframe id="myFrame1" name="myFrame" ></iframe>
<iframe id="myFrame2" name="myFrame" ></iframe>

   <form method="post" action="tesb.php" target="#myFrame0" name="form1">
        <input name="sent"  type="text" id="sent1" /> 
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="tesb.php" target="#myFrame1" name="form2">
        <input  name="sent"  type="text" id="sent2" /> 
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="tesb.php" target="#myFrame2" name="form3">
        <input name="sent"  type="text" id="sent3" /> 
    </form>
```

that's the resulting xhtml after php (so.. it may be more than three forms / iframes)

one simple link to call a javascript function

```
<a href='#' id="other">Click Here To Submit the Forms </a>
```

this is my script, really simple btw

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#other').click(function() {  
    $('#myFrame0').submit();
    $('#myFrame1').submit();
    $('#myFrame2').submit();
    });
});
```

ok, the question is:

the inputs doesn't post at all but, if i add a submit button (input type=submit) it will perfectyl post just one of the three forms ..

this is the destination php (just to see if everything is posted)

```
<? 
echo $_POST["sent"];
?>
```

the rules are..

1. i can't edit testb.php (destination.. since that's a blackbox from an existing system)
2. i can just send one item at a time.
3. no sessions, no arrays, no url post

but i need to send several forms one by one to the same destination.. and it has to be one by one.

any clue to fix or improve my script?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the id in the target attribute is without "#"

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/RaFvH/)   does not work the reception of the post, but it works as an example

try this:

HTML:

```
<iframe id="myFrame0" name="myFrame" ></iframe>
<iframe id="myFrame1" name="myFrame" ></iframe>
<iframe id="myFrame2" name="myFrame" ></iframe>

   <form method="post" action="tesb.php" target="#myFrame0" name="form1">
        <input name="sent"  type="text" id="sent1" /> 
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="tesb.php" target="#myFrame1" name="form2">
        <input  name="sent"  type="text" id="sent2" /> 
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="tesb.php" target="#myFrame2" name="form3">
        <input name="sent"  type="text" id="sent3" /> 
    </form>


<a href='#' id="other">Click Here To Submit the Forms </a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#other').click(function() {  
       $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd re-write how but basically this covers a couple of approaches: [ajax submit multiple forms via jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340741/ajax-submit-multiple-forms-via-jquery)