# submitting multiple forms with one submit button

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have an application where in a signed in user searches a database and is displayed a table of results.  These results are basically listings of events. I give the user then, the privilege to "keep" or "discard" any event (using radio buttons beside each event).

Now however, I wish to implement a functionality whereby, the user at the end can click just one "update" button and all changes are affected (since keeping one button for each record will be very user unfriendly). That is, I am looking equivalently to submit multiple forms with just one submit/update button.

Is this possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340741/ajax-submit-multiple-forms-via-jquery

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362251/jquery-submit-multiple-forms

Answer (score 4):

You need to use javascript, I suggest you using JQuery. Using AJAX you need to submit each form - this way page will not be redirected once you submit a form!

Then, within each forms assign individual IDs for each form. Then, assign your submit button an id for example `mySubmit`. Up next, add following code:

```
$('#mySubmit').click(function(){
    // submit form1 by ajax...
    // submit form2 by ajax...
});
```

You may see jQuery's http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ for further information on how to submit a form using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all of the radio buttons and submit button are part of the same form, you don't need to worry about submitting multiple forms because there won't be any.  You can have multiple submit buttons in a single form, you can give them different values to know which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery then use javascript to form a list of data separated by say ~ character and set this string to some hidden field and submit using document.formx.submit()

You will need to parse the string on server side to get the data in correct format.